# ¿Como Eliminar Hora De Un Datatime En Consulta LINQ en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy realizando un consulta a Una Base de datos de **Mysql** y quiero mostrar el resultado en un `DatagridView` mi problema es que me despliega la fecha con la hora y solo necesito la fecha he probado con

```
.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

y

```
.ToShortDateString()
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error en ejecucion.

> LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.String
>   ToString(System.String)' del método, y este método no se puede
>   traducir en una expresión de almacén.

este es mi codigo.

```
TEntities db = new TEntities();

var reporte = from consul in db.Transaccion 
              where consul.Cliente_idCliente == idCli 
              select new { Codigo = consul.idTransaccion, 
                           Fecha = consul.fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                           Valor = consul.valor, 
                           otra = consul.denominacion + " " + 
                           consul.noAutorizacion
                          };

dataGridView1.DataSource = reporte.ToList() ;
```

Comment: Dónde realizas la conversión? en la consulta que publicaste no aparece ninguna conversión de `Datetime` a `String`

Comment: en la consulta de linq he probado hacer la conversion pero el error es el mismo

Comment: Eso sucede por que Linq esta tratando de convertir el metodo `ToString` o el `ToShortDateString` a una equivalente a SQL, Digamos que no todos los metodos son compatibles. Leete este enlace: [Asignar un método CLR a una función canónica](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/clr-method-to-canonical-function-mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se da debido a que Linq to Entities no tiene definición para `ToString()`.

Para poder hacerlo con `ToString()` podrías ejecutar `AsEnumerable()` (que va a producir que la consulta a la base de datos se ejecute) y luego, ya habiéndose ejecutado la query, el uso de `ToString()` sería válido.

Por ejemplo:

```
var reporte = db.Transaccion.Where(c => c.Cliente_idCliente == idCli).AsEnumerable()
                .select(c => 
                new
                {
                    Codigo = c.idTransaccion,
                    Fecha = c.fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    Valor = c.valor,
                    otra = c.denominacion + " " + c.noAutorizacion
                });
```

Aclaro que si manejas muchos registros dudo que esta sea una solución muy performante

---

Edit: Agrego la opción de configurarlo desde el `DataGridView` como plantea [Orlando De La Rosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/107347/orlando-de-la-rosa) que sería claramente mejor práctica que lo de arriba

Para configurar la visualización del campo en un `DataGridView` basta con modificar la propiedad `Format` de `DefaultCellStyle` de la columna requerida.

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que la primer columna es en la que se visualiza la fecha,podrías formatearlo así

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: Solo para tener en cuenta, esta manera cargará **todas** las columnas de la tabla.  En muchos casos no es un problema pero si por ejemplo tienes 100 columnas y solo usas 4, estás trayendo datos que no necesitas.

Comment: Podrias editar tu respuesta y gregarle una segun opcion y es editarle el formato a la columna del [dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726576), de esta forma no debe de tocar la consulta.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa el problema radica al momento de traer los datos desde la BD, no en la generación y visualización de los datos

Comment: Por lo mismo, para que convertirlo en la consulta si el control de grilla que utiliza ya lo hace.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias por la idea, ahí agregue

Comment: No es que no tenga un ToString, es que la instrucción linq se convierte en instrucción sql, y no sabe como convertir el tostring a sql. Para funciones de conversiones de cadena se puede usar SqlFunctions.StringConvert

Comment: Si no me equivoco ningun metodo sobre cargado de `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` soporta como argumento un objeto `Datetime`, al menos que se utilize `SqlFunctions.DateName`